# Host to setup DotNet project with sonarqube with code coverage and unittests

Tags: .net, sonarqube

How to setup an existing DotNet project to be analyzed in sonarqube, and to show the code coverage, and unit tests.

The normal process:
dotnet sonarscanner begin ...
dotnet build
dotnet sonarscanner end

Misses the code coverage, and unit tests part.

Answer (score 0):

After one and half day, the solution with docker:
The build steps are commented out, but might be part of your CI/CD process.

One liner docker command:

```
PROJECT_DIR: absolute path of project directory
ARTIFACT_DIR: where should be the final product built
PROJECT_NAME: Project Key in sonarqube
SONARQUBE_URL: Full URL of sonarqube server, with protocol and port
SONARQUBE_TOKEN: Access token (generate one at project or administration -> users -> token)


docker run --rm -v ${PROJECT_DIR}:/opt/build/:z \
-v ${ARTIFACT_DIR}:/opt/build/artifact:z \
-v nugets:/root/.nuget \
-w /opt/build \
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 \
sh -c 'export PATH="$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools" && \
apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jdk-headless && \
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-sonarscanner && \
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-coverage && \
dotnet sonarscanner begin /k:"PROJECT_NAME" /d:sonar.host.url="${SONARQUBE_URL}" /d:sonar.login="${SONARQUBE_TOKEN}" /d:sonar.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths=coverage.xml  /d:sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths=artifacts/test-results/*.trx && \
dotnet restore  && \
#dotnet build  --no-restore -c Release -o /opt/build/artifact/build -p:IsPipelineBuild=1 && \
dotnet-coverage collect "dotnet test -l:trx --results-directory artifacts/test-results" -f xml -o "coverage.xml" && \
dotnet-trx2sonar -d ./ -o ./SonarTestResults.xml && \
dotnet publish  --no-build -c Release -p:PublishDir=/opt/build/artifact/publish -p:OutDir=/opt/build/artifact/build && \
dotnet sonarscanner end /d:sonar.login="${SONARQUBE_TOKEN}"
```

as Dockerfile:

```
PROJECT_NAME: Project Key in sonarqube
SONARQUBE_URL: Full URL of sonarqube server, with protocol and port
SONARQUBE_TOKEN: Access token (generate one at project or administration -> users -> token)


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0
RUN export PATH="$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jdk-headless
RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-coverage
RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-sonarscanner
# The exact build steps
# you might want to restore the project
# dotnet restore && \
CMD dotnet sonarscanner begin /k:"$PROJECT_NAME" /d:sonar.host.url="$SONARQUBE_URL" /d:sonar.login="$SONARQUBE_TOKEN" \
    /d:sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths=coverage.xml \
    /d:sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths=artifacts/test-results/*.trx && \
    dotnet-coverage collect "dotnet test -l:trx --results-directory artifacts/test-results" -f xml -o "coverage.xml" && \
    # you might want to a build here \
    dotnet sonarscanner end /d:sonar.login="$SONARQUBE_TOKEN"
```

How to execute:
docker run --rm -v nugets:/root/.nuget -v ${PROJECT_DIR}:/opt/build image_name